# Constructor taking char pointer

Tags: c++

This is going to be a basic question, but hope someone can help me..

I have function like this;

```
void createInstance()
{
   MyClass m_Class;
   m_Class(25, "Roger")(32, "Pete")(56, "Haley")(89, "Tom");
}
```

Now in the MyClass:

```
class MyClass 
{
    MyClass();
    MyClass(int, const char&); // Gets ERROR here...
};
```

I want to write a constructor in **MyClass** that can take line #2 from **createInstance** function.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obligatory: why do you want to do this, and what do you want it to do? In terms of making it compile, you have to understand that the way it's written, your object is already constructed. The second line is not a constructor call at all, but calling operator() on your object, which you haven't defined. Do you want to create multiple objects, or do you want to be able to flexibly pass multiple of these int, string pairs to your object post construction? If you want to do the latter, you can do this:

```
class MyClass 
{
    MyClass();

    MyClass& operator()(int x, const char* str) {
        // Do stuff with x and str
        return *this;
    }
};
```

What's clever about this is that the operator() returns a reference to the object itself, which of course has the operator(), so you can call it again, which again returns a reference to the object, and so on. Here's a working example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0873be09770afd2.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

MyClass(int, const char*);

Comment: Gives Error - error: no match for call to ‘(MyClass) (int, const char [4])’|

Comment: getting error - error: no match for call to ‘(MyClass) (int, const char [4])’